# Strange behaviour of Translate animation of a view in android

Tags: android, animation, viewgroup, translate-animation

I am animating a view with translate animation but it is behaving strange at 1 situation among 6. I am having a single view which to be added left or right (one at a time ) with proper animation as inFromLeft/outToRight/etc. For an example If my view is available at left and i want to animate it to left using left handle then out to left animation will take place which is handled properly in my code . Similarly if my view is available in right and i want to animate it using left then steps to be followed as :

`(1)out from right animation and remove from right.`

`(2) add to left and in from left animation`

This is again right in my code.

But for the similar case but reverse in current position as

if my view is in left and i want to animate the view from right handle then steps to be followed as:

`(1) Out to left animation and remove from left view group then`

`(2) adding it to right and then in From right animation.`

when i am doing this its not animating properly.

[image: Pictorial view of Steps i Followed]

also adding image link [Image link for step i followed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C9Pqrvc_CWQmVsZG8zXzZ1alE/edit?usp=sharing)

I am attaching my application code , please tell me what wrong i am doing for this particular situation  [Link for complete src code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C9Pqrvc_CWVWc4V3lYMFlla0k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have run your project on Nexus 4. It's working fine. Also, I want to know what do you mean by "It's not taking *properly* " ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto problem is when view is available at left and clicking right handle . then its going out properly but its not coming properly from right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case i am using `Thread.sleep(longTime)` for 2 consecutive animation but its was creating problem. 
I did it using `Handler with postDelayed(longtime)` as follows which was doing directly in `onAnimationEnd()`.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    inFromRight();
  }
 }, 100);
```

Comment: Great.. I was also stucked in this.